# Efficient Method of Selecting Parent Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I’m doing DOM manipulation on a site (I don’t have access to the source code) and would like to know if there’s a better way of selecting an element on a page using jQuery.  What typically happens is a requester asks to change something on a page (like text or swap an image) and I look at the source and the item they want to change doesn’t have an ID – just class names up the DOM chain.  For example, I’d get something like “can you change Automobiles to Hotels in the right rail” and the HTML on the page looks like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="products">
      <div class="sidebarText">Telephones</div>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
      <div class="sidebarText">Automobiles</div>
  </div>
  <div class="products">
      <div class="sidebarText">Computers</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I currently do is manually count the number of times the class I needed to change appears from the top of the page to build the selector, test it in Firebug’s console and go on about my business.  The final code would look like this:

```
jQuery('.sidebarText').eq(1).html('Hotels');
```

While this works, manually counting DIVs on a page clearly isn’t an efficient method of selecting DOM elements so I was wondering if there is a better way.  In laymen’s terms, I was hoping there’s a way to “*select the parent DIV when the word automobiles is found but only if that parent DIV is sidebartext*”.

On a related note, this would also be easier if Firebug had an option/plugin that copied the jQuery selector instead of the xPath (/html/body/div/div[2]/div) or CSS paths (html body div div.products div.sidebarText) – that would make both of my options above unnecessary (and super helpful).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `:contains(text)`:

```
$("div.sidebartext:contains('Automobiles')").text("Hotels");
```

Two caveats: it is case-sensitive and selector above will match "Super Automobiles" as well as "Automobiles".

Comment: Why `div.sidebartext` instead of just `.sidebartext`?

Comment: @jfriend00, to be a bit more specific. Who knows what this class is for? It might not be used only for div's in question. Also it fits what OP is looking for: `only if that parent DIV is sidebartext`